# How to copy photos from SD Card to External Storage?

Tags: samsung, file-management

I want to copy my photos 22GB from my external SD Card on my phone to my Mac or USB Drive by OTG.

However, I have been trying to use 3rd party Files Manager "ASUS File Manager" as well as Samsung's My Files, but both of them result the date of my photo to be current time, not original photo's time.

I have been trying to copy the folder of DCIM to my Mac via Android File Transfer, but it doesn't work too (always error and quit).

Anyone can share me how to copy the photos and keep the original photo's time?

Comment: The date you see is the creation time of the file or the last time the file was written. To get the actual date of capture, take a look at the EXIF information inside the file itself. In case you absolute have to preserve the file system information, moving the files is the only automatic way I can think that preserves those times.

Comment: @GiantTree I don't think moving will do the trick, as across file system boundaries that's nothing but "copy + delete".

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- fix date and time via Exif as described by [GiantTree](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/86358/gianttree) in his comment on your question (there are tools for that; if you've no idea which, please see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)) – or
- simply use an app on the device to ZIP the files, then copy the ZIP to your Mac and unzip again (for "which app", again see above link). As this is not really practicable for 22GB:
- option #3 would be to shutdown your phone, take out the SD card, and use a card-reader to connect it to your Mac and copy the files directly. This is probably the easiest approach to your problem.

I don't think moving will do the trick, as across file system boundaries that's nothing but "copy + delete".

Comment: No need to shutdown, it is possible to unmount the card and then take it out.

Comment: Sure it is, @Alex.S – but shutting it down is the safest way (and the easiest to explain). See: [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Samsung Smart Switch](https://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/)?

I use it on my mac and it works fine!

Comment: Does "it works fine" include "it keeps the timestamps"?